# Time complexity of inserting at the beginning of LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am curious about the time complexity of inserting an element at the beginning of a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).  I understand the LinkedList itself will shift the existing elements one index to the right but, to do that, will it make as many iterations as there are existing elements in the list?

Also, is the best way to insert at the beginning [offerFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#offerFirst%28E%29) ?

Comment: Why should the remaining elements be shifted? The head will point to the new element, and its next will point to the previous head. So should it not be O(1)?

Comment: shift as they would in an ArrayList, so the former element 0 is now 1

Comment: A linked list is not an array.  You are creating I presume a queue.  A queue can be implemented using either a linked list or an array.  A linked list is just manipulation of pointers to memory.  No shifting involved.

Comment: Inserting element at any end of LinkedList is very fast as well as removing or retrieving. If you want to know more of methods like offerFirst then cover [Internal life of LinkedLIst](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/05/internal-life-of-linkedlist-in-java.html) tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to the front of a `LinkedList` occurs in constant time:

```
public void addFirst(E e) 
{
    addBefore(e, header.next);
}

private Entry<E> addBefore(E e, Entry<E> entry) 
{
    Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(e, entry, entry.previous);
    newEntry.previous.next = newEntry;
    newEntry.next.previous = newEntry;
    size++;
    modCount++;

    return newEntry;
}
```

It is not backed by an array whose elements need to be shifted.  As you can see, all that needs to be done is a set of reference reassignments.

**EDIT:**

To address your concern about `offerFirst`, all it is is:

```
public boolean offerFirst(E e) 
{
     addFirst(e); 

     return true;
}
```

So, as I said in the comment, only use it if you want a `boolean` returned.

Comment: is it OK to just use `offerFirst`? i.e. if i do it, will the List automatically shift the rest for me?

Comment: See the code and my explanation.  This is not an `ArrayList`--it is not backed by an array.  A `LinkedList` is a set of nodes with references to the `previous` and `next` nodes.  Hence, you add and delete nodes by reassigning references.  There is no need to shift anything.

Comment: OK.  how about the actual insertion.  should i just use `offerFirst`?

Comment: If you want a `boolean` returned, otherwise `addFirst` is fine.

Comment: @amphibient In addition to the comment above, I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting an item at the front of the list will only do two things (both very lightweight):

1) Update the HEAD Pointer (This is the pointer that tells us where the first element is)

2) Set the NEXT pointer of the new element to be the old HEAD element.

This is a very lightweight operation, and represents one of the strengths of a Linked List.

I do not know Java very well, but since offerFirst is designed to add an element to the front of the list, it is probably the best way to do it.